# Exchange 2003 Delete Specific Emails

Tags: exchange-2003

Over the weekend our Exchange server was blasted with emails.  Using recipient policies in the mailbox manager, how do I remove emails that are in the inbox, but coming from a specific sender (or maybe containing a specific subject?).  Perhaps someone has some suggestions for another route to take aside from recipient policies, but that will affectively achieve the same end goal?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do that with the Mailbox Manager Settings in Recipient Policy. There are no "content" settings that I'm aware of. You can enable the settings based on size or age.

Answer (score 2):

Exmerge should do the trick, I would investigate the reason the the blast and act accordingly.

Comment: Exmerge is going to be fairly limited in it's ability to do this. If you try to Exmerge the email based on the date you'll wind up losing legitimate email. If you try to Exmerge based on subject or attachment and your dealing with hundreds of different subject lines or attachments in these spam emails then it's going to be an exercise in futility.